# Unable to send the message again using C socket

Tags: c++, sockets

I have created a ClientSocket and a ServerSocket class for simplifying functions. while sending a data, at first I am sending a 16 bytes header containing the message length followed by the message. But I am having trouble while sending data from client to server on the 2nd time. At first it is sending the header and the message properly but after that I am getting 0 bytes output from `read()` in `ServerSocket::get_message` while reading the header from the client. Please help me out here.

Sending and receiving part in Server.cpp

```cpp
    string ServerSocket::get_message(int client_socket_fd) {
        //char *header = client_buffers[client_socket_fd].read_header;
        char *read_buffer = client_buffers[client_socket_fd].read_buffer;
        char header[16];
        memset(header, 0, sizeof(header));
        int read_result = -1;
        read_result = read(client_socket_fd, header, 16);
        cout << read_result << endl;
        if (read_result > 0){
            int read_size = stoi(string(header));
            cout << read_size << endl;
            memset(read_buffer, 0, sizeof(read_buffer));
            read_result = read(client_socket_fd, read_buffer,read_size);
            if (read_result > 0) return string(read_buffer);
        }
        cerr << "Unable to recieve message from client socket " << client_socket_fd << endl;
        return "";
    }

    int ServerSocket::_send(int client_socket_fd, string message) {
        //char *header = client_buffers[client_socket_fd].write_header;
        char *write_buffer = client_buffers[client_socket_fd].write_buffer;
        char header[16];
        memset(header, 0, sizeof(header));
        string write_size = to_string(message.length());
        copy(write_size.begin(), write_size.end(), header);
        int write_result = write(client_socket_fd, header, 16); // sending size of message

        if (write_result > 0) {
            write_result = write(client_socket_fd, message.c_str(), message.length());
        }
        if (write_result <= 0)
            cerr << "Unable to send to client socket fd : " << client_socket_fd << endl; 
        return write_result;
    }
```

Sending and receiving part in Client.cpp

```cpp
    string ClientSocket::_recieve(){
        char read_header[16];
        memset(read_header, 0, sizeof(read_header));
        int read_result = read(socket_fd, read_header, 16);
        if (read_result >0) {
            int read_size = stoi(string(read_header));
            memset(recieve_buffer, 0, sizeof(recieve_buffer));
            read_result = read(socket_fd, recieve_buffer, read_size);
        }
        if ( read_result > 0) return string(recieve_buffer);
        cerr << "Unable to read from server." << endl;
        return "";
    }
    int ClientSocket::_send(string message) {
        char write_header[16];
        memset(write_header, 0, sizeof(write_header));
        cout << message.length() << endl;
        string s = to_string(message.length());
        copy(s.begin(),s.end(), write_header);
        int write_result = write(socket_fd, write_header, 16);
        if (write_result > 0)
            write_result = write(socket_fd, message.c_str(), message.length());
        if (write_result <=0) cerr << "Unable to send message : "<< message  << endl;
        return write_result;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code exhibits the two most frequent errors when using sockets:

1. Socket `send`/`write` and `recv`/`read` may not send/receive the number of bytes requested. The code must handle partial reads/writes in order to work correctly.
2. The received socket data is not zero-terminated. You need to zero-terminate the received data before passing it to functions that expect zero-terminated stings (`std::string` and `stoi` here). `memset` doesn't help when `recv` fills the entire buffer, you need to reserve one extra byte for the null terminator that `recv` doesn't overwrite.